# App getting crashed after updating latest Huawei Awareness Kit in flutter

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I am implementing Huawei Awareness Kit from github in flutter. With updated version in gradle that says "A newer version of com.huawei.agconnect:agcp than 1.5.2.300 is available: 1.6.0.300".After updating to new version and when clicking the  **"query capabilities demo" button** ,the app getting crash.

Comment: any flutter log or android logcat info you can find?

Comment: Can you share the crash logs here?

Answer (score 0):

1-Check build.gradle in the project, whether the code of the agc plugin is configured "apply plugin:'com.huawei.agconnect"
2-add below plugin in app level - build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'

and you can try below solutions.

1. Check whether the related ability switch of AppGallery Connect console is turned on;
2. Whether agconnect-services.json has been updated after turning on the switch;